error 'console' is not defined no-undef with eslint 9 jest
This question isn't a duplicate. I have read through this question: ERROR: 'console is not defined. [no-undef] - Brackets and most of the answers are for ESLint 8 and below. Some have talked about the flat config file, which I have attempted to no avail:
// filename: eslint.config.js
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import jest from "eslint-plugin-jest";

export default [
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  {
    files: ["**/*.js"],
    languageOptions: {
      globals: { ...globals.node },
    },
    ...jest.configs["flat/recommended"],
    plugins: {
      jest,
    },
    rules: {},
  },
];

I have tried many modifications, such as globals: { ...globals.browser, ...globals.node } and using the 'no-console': 'off' rule, but every time I run npm run lint, I still get:
  6:3  error  'console' is not defined  no-undef

Here is my index.js file:
import app from "./src/app.js";

const PORT = 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

I am really out of options.`
Edit: Most answers on the question I linked are not applicable because they are using the .eslintrc file, which has been deprecated in ESLint 9, as well as properties like env.
When I run npm run lint, it runs the following:
    "lint": "eslint '**/*.js' --ignore-pattern node_modules/",


I don't see that you have tried any of the solutions from the link you posted.  Did you try setting up a .eslintrc as described?

Eslint 9 doesn't support .eslintrc file and deprecated the env property. So most solutions don't apply, but only those that are using the flat config

globals: { ...globals.node } is ok. "flat config file" - what is file name and what is npm run lint script exactly? First of all check that eslint config is applied, i.e. add syntax error to it. It should fail. If it doesn't, that's the problem

I have updated the answer with more details. To answer your question, the ESLint config is being applied successfully as prior to adding the Jest plugin, I was getting expect and describe undefined errors, which I fixed.
